# kubectl: get specific value from a secret in plaintext

Tags: kubernetes, posix, kubectl

I want to get the value of a specific field of a secret in a shell script.

From the `kubectl get secret` documentation, it seems the standard way to get a secret returns the whole thing, in a specified format, with the values base64 encoded.

So, to get the `bar` field of the `foo` secret, output as an unencoded string, I'm doing this:

```sh
kubectl get secret foo -o json | jq -r ".data.bar" | base64 --decode
```

That is

- get the whole `foo` secret as JSON
- pipe to `jq` to read the `bar` field from the JSON
- decode the value using `base64`

**Is there a way to do this only using `kubectl`?**

Or an elegant way in POSIX-compliant shell that doesn't rely on any dependencies like `jq`?

Comment: Try this `kubectl get secret foo --template={{.data.bar}} | base64 --decode` no need of jq

Comment: I don't know of any way to decode base64 using kubectl's internal mechanisms, but to get specific field from the secret, you can use jsonpath output: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/  - You can pipe/combine the output with one of the methods here, to avoid base64 command dependency as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800145/base-64-decoding-in-shell-scripting

Comment: You can try using sed `kubectl get secret foo | sed 's/^.*bar: \(.*\).*$/\1/' | base64 -d`

Comment: These are all very helpful options, thanks! Please post them as answers so I can upvote!

Comment: `$ kubectl get secret foo -o=jsonpath='{.data.bar}' | base64 -d` but still need to pipe to base64 to decode.

Comment: I think is nothing better can @mchawre answer,

Comment: Let me put it as answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this

```
kubectl get secret foo --template={{.data.bar}} | base64 --decode
```

No need of jq.

Comment: It doesn't work now, if there's a hyphen in the name.

Answer (score 15):

In cases when key contains dots:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: foo
data:
  bar.baz: RnVja2VkIFVwIEJleW9uZCBBbGwgUmVjb2duaXRpb24=
```

the syntax would be:

```sh
kubectl get secret foo -o jsonpath="{.data['bar\.baz']}" | base64 -d
```

Answer (score 11):

```
kubectl get secret foo -o jsonpath={.data.bar} | base64 --decode
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

Comment: This approach works for me even when the path contains a hyphen. Using `--template` doesn't (at least, not without some level of escaping it, which, well, escaped _me_)

Comment: Just added a new answer showing the escaping for decoding secrets from hyphenated paths/keys directly from kubectl without needing to pipe to an external base64 executable.

Answer (score 9):

You can try the following command, it will decode all the values in the secret.

```
kubectl get secret <secret-name> -o json | jq '.data | map_values(@base64d)'
```

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 8):

This should work since Kubernetes 1.11 (see [PR 60755](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/60755)):

`kubectl get secret foo -o go-template='{{ .data.bar | base64decode }}'`

Answer (score 5):

For a hyphenated key, here's the escaping trick to get the decoded value directly from `kubectl`:

```
kubectl get secret foo -o go-template='{{ index .data \"bar-baz\" | base64decode }}'
```

(Tested with kubectl 1.21.5)

Comment: Question stipulates, “Is there a way to do this only using kubectl?” and besides actually answering the question, this answer deals correctly with the case of the secret key having a dot or dash. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you guys coming here via Google and want to do it from **PowerShell**, where `base64` ist not available, use the following:

```powershell
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($(kubectl get secret foo -o jsonpath='{.data.bar}')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comprehensive bash solution:

> kubereadsecret() {
> secretname=$1
> shift
> dataname=$1
> shift
> keyname="{.data['$(echo $dataname | sed 's/[.]/\./g')']}"
> kubectl get secret $secretname -o jsonpath=$keyname $* | base64 --decode
> }

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using `jq` to get all decoded values of a secret:

```bash
kubectl get -o json secret/${secret_name} | jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | [.key, (.value | @base64d)] | @csv'
```